# Derivation of the formula of the vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to derive the formula for vector potentials,
$$\vec{A} = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4{\pi}} \int \frac {\vec{j} (\vec{r}')} {\lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert} \mathrm{d} \vec{r}' $$
from the Biot and Savart formula
$$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_{0}}{4{\pi}} \int \frac {\vec{j} (\vec{r}') \times ( \vec{r} - \vec{r}' ) } {{\lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert}^{3} } \mathrm{d} \vec{r}' .$$

I saw that the key of the derivation is to write
$$ {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}} \times \frac {\vec{j} (\vec{r}')} {\lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert} = \frac { {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}} \times \vec{j} (\vec{r}') } { \lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert } - \vec{j} (\vec{r}') \times \left ( {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}} \times \frac {1} { \lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert } \right ) =  \vec{j} (\vec{r}') \times \frac {\vec{r} - \vec {r}' } {{\lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert}^{3} } ,$$
but I don't understand why
$$ \frac { {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}} \times \vec{j} (\vec{r}') } { \lvert \overrightarrow{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert } - \vec{j} (\vec{r}') \times \left ( {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}} \times \frac {1} { \lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert } \right ) =  \vec{j} (\vec{r}') \times \frac {\vec{r} - \vec {r}' } {{\lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert}^{3} }. $$

Also, what is the difference between ${\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}}$ and $ {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}'}$ ?

Comment: Look up vector identities involving the curl of a scalar multiplied by a vector and you shall have your answer. The primes as you know denote the source coordinates and the unprimed are the field coordinates. So you can take the grad with respect to both these coordinates and the subscript denotes just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between ${\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}}$ and $ {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}'}$ is that the former represents derivatives with respect to $\vec r$, and the latter differentiates with respect to $\vec r'$.

The formula that puzzles you,
$$ \frac { {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}} \times \vec{j} (\vec{r}') } { \lvert \overrightarrow{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert } - \vec{j} (\vec{r}') \times \left ( {\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}} \color{\red}{\times} \frac {1} { \lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert } \right ) =  \vec{j} (\vec{r}') \times \frac {\vec{r} - \vec {r}' } {{\lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert}^{3} }, $$
has two things going on.

- One is the term in ${\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}} \times \vec{j} (\vec{r}')$, which vanishes because $\vec{j} (\vec{r}') $ does not depend on $\vec r$, and therefore under the action of $\vec\nabla_\vec{r}$ it gives zero.
- The other is the gradient (not the curl!) of the relative separation, 
  $${\vec{\nabla}}_{\vec{r}}  \frac {1} { \lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert } = -\frac {\vec{r} - \vec {r}' } {{\lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert}^{3} },$$
  which reduces to a simple calculation. As an example, for the $x$ component of the gradient, and setting $\tilde r=\lvert \vec{r} - \vec{r}' \rvert$, we have
  $$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{\tilde r} = -\frac{1}{\tilde r^2} \frac{\partial \tilde r}{\partial x},
  $$
  where
  \begin{align}
  \frac{\partial \tilde r}{\partial x}
  & = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}
  \\& = \frac{2(x-x')}{2\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}}
  \\& = \frac{(x-x')}{\tilde r},
  \end{align}
  so
  $$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{\tilde r} = -\frac{x-x'}{\tilde r^3},
  $$
  as claimed.